# Attribute directive scope.apply not working when used within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an attribute directive to update the DOM, a variable called `profileImage`. The attribute directive is called `ppt-profile-icon` and works fine as long as it is not inside `ng-repeat`. I have looked through a myriad of questions on Stackoverflow and have not found a solution.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="img-preview" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + profileImage + ')'}"></div>


<ul class="dropdown-menu pre-defined-icons" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
    <li ng-repeat="predefinedImage in vm.predefinedImages">
        <a>
            <img ppt-profile-icon src="{{predefinedImage}}" width="100%" />
        </a>
    </li>

    <!--This, outside of the ng-repeat will work-->
    <li>
        <a>
            <img ppt-profile-icon src="content/img/people/noProfileIcon.svg" width="100%" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is my directive:

```
angular
    .module('app.core')
    .directive('pptProfileIcon', function ($timeout) {
        //link function for DOM Minipulation
        function linkFunction(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function () {
                scope.profileImage = attrs.src;
                scope.$apply();
            });

        }//end

        //Directive Declaration
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                //sets enviornment
            }],
            link: linkFunction
        }//end

    });//end
```

In my `link` function I have tried:

```
attrs.$observe('src', function (val) {
    $timeout(function () {
        scope.profileImage = val;
        scope.$apply();
    });
});

$timeout(function () {
    scope.profileImage = attrs.src;
    scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: using `$scope.$apply` is, in general, a code smell.  There are ways to fix this so that `$apply` would work again, but this should be an indication that finding a cleaner way to do your update that doesn't involve `$apply` would be a good investment of time.

Comment: @Claies I agree, I do not like where I am at with this,  it is a commercial project so I am trying to cut corners with only this so far, my whole app, otherwise is components, AngularJs 1.5 style, all one way binding. No scope. This directive is here because of I have an input type=file and I can't manipulate the DOM with my component base on a file.Reader event. This directive is actually used only in a component and it is code smell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, `scope` in your directive is the `ngRepeat` directive's scope, not the parent so you're only setting `profileImage` within the repeater.

I'd go with an executable binding

```
.directive('pptProfileIcon', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            pptProfileIcon: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            elem.on('click', function() {
                scope.pptProfileIcon({
                    profileImage: elem.prop('src')
                });
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Then, create a function in your controller scope to set the image

```
$scope.setProfileImage = function(image) {
    $scope.profileImage = image;
};
```

and set your template like this

```
<img ppt-profile-icon="setProfileImage(profileImage)" ng-src="{{predefinedImage}}" />
```

Plunker demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/GqFXqZW5AmLCyWHblBDN?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

you should always use object in your *ngModels* when interacting between parend - child scopes (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes for more details), so just adding vm.model before primitives would be sufficient:

```
<div class="img-preview" 
     ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + vm.model.profileImage + ')'}"></div>
```

and in the link function:

```
    //link function for DOM Minipulation
    function linkFunction(scope, elem, attrs) {

        elem.bind('click', function () {
          scope.vm.model.profileImage = attrs.src;
          scope.$apply();
        });

    }//end
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jddW7zURZoyLA8MKkm6t?p=preview